# regexp rule which returns column entries of text database

Tags: regex, matlab

given a simple delimiter separated text database, I want to construct a regexp rule, which returns the column / field entries.

given the following two example lines

```
entry1 = '|123|some|string   |101112  |'
entry2 = '|123|some|  |101112  |'
```

i want to get the following output:

```
values1 = '123', 'some', 'string', '101112'
values2 = '123', 'some', '', '101112'
```

so far I'm using the following `regexp` and `regexprep` combination:

```
values = regexp(regexprep(entry '[\s]', ''), '\|', 'split')
```

which unfortunately returns the following:

```
values1 =  ''    '123'    'some'    'string'    '101112'    ''
values2 =  ''    '123'    'some'    ''    '101112'    ''
```

but I want to get (no extra `''` before the `123` and not extra `''` after `'101112'`):

```
values1 = '123', 'some', 'string', '101112'
values2 = '123', 'some', '', '101112'
```

given my regexp rule, why do I get the `''` at the beginning and the end? How do I have to change my regexp rule, to only return the field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is exactly what you are asking for, but you can use `strread`:

```
strread(entry1(2:end),'%d','delimiter','|')
ans =
         123
         456
         789
      101112
```

Comment: thanks! how does `strread` perform compared to `regexp`? I have to parse thousands of lines ... I've made an edit to my original posting to hopefully explain what I want. But yes, your solution works. Except that if a field is empty (see `entry2`), your code will return `0` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Empty strings are there because you tell matlab to split at `|` characters. And splitting means that you cut there. If there is nothing before `|`, you'll get empty string. For example, splitting this (subresult after `regexprep`):

```
'|123|456|789|101112|'
```

results in (imagine cutting the string at `|`):

```
'', '123', '456', '789', '101112', ''
```

So, either split the string between the first and the last `|`:

```
nospaces = regexprep(entry, '\s', '')
betweenpipes = nospaces(2:size(nospaces,2)-1)
values = regexp(betweenpipes, '\|', 'split')
```

..or don't use split at all and just search for the required pattern:

```
regexp(entry, '(?=\)(?:\s*)(\d+)(?:\s*)(?=\)', 'match')
```

Regexp explained:

1. look for `|`, but don't remember it: `(?=\|)`
2. skip possible whitespace but don't remember it: `(?:\s*)`
3. match a number: `(\d+)`
4. skip possible whitespace but don't remember it: `(?:\s*)`
5. look for `|`, but don't remember it: `(?=\|)`

I'm writing this from memory as I don't have matlab here, so there may be some bugs..

Comment: unfortunately your `regexp` rule returns `{}` :( I fixed the mistake in your code (from `(?=\)` to `(?=\|)`) but it still doesn't work.